# Azure webjob logs - looking for logs that detail the SDK's handling of queue triggered items

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

As shown in my Stack Overflow question [Azure webjob not appearing to respect MaxDequeueCount property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260068/azure-webjob-not-appearing-to-respect-maxdequeuecount-property), I'm troubleshooting a problem where despite my setting of the MaxDequeueCount property to 1, some items are dequeued many times before they're poisoned (in fact some items may never be poisoned at all and just dequeue, fail and are retried and fail endlessly).

The Webjobs SDK handles the retries and poisoning of queue triggered messages automatically and I'm looking for logs that contain details of that handling.

For example, I can see that my function has detected a new queue item by viewing the webjob's log through the SCM at `https://myappengine.scm.azurewebsites.net/vfs/data/jobs/continuous/StuffProcessor/job_log.txt` (By the way if I've enabled detailed logging to Azure storage on the web app can I get this same info in a Blob?).

```
[02/22/2017 01:47:22 > ec8d0f: INFO] Executing: 'StuffProcessor.ProcessQueueMessage' - Reason: 'New queue message detected on 'stuff-processor'.'
[02/22/2017 01:47:26 > ec8d0f: INFO] Executed: 'StuffProcessor.ProcessQueueMessage' (Succeeded)
[02/22/2017 01:47:26 > ec8d0f: INFO] Executing: 'StuffProcessor.ProcessQueueMessage' - Reason: 'New queue message detected on 'stuff-processor'.'
```

I can also get some information on an item's dequeue count by viewing the logs in the `azure-jobs-host-archive` container once I've enabled detailed logging to Azure storage on the web app:

```
{
      "Type": "FunctionCompleted",
      "EndTime": "2017-02-22T00:07:40.8133081+00:00",
      "Failure": {
        "ExceptionType": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException",
        "ExceptionDetails": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: ItemProcessor.ProcessQueueMessage ---> MyApp.Exceptions.MySpecialAppExceptionType: Exception of type 'MyApp.Exceptions.MySpecialAppExceptionType' was thrown.
      },
      "ParameterLogs": {},
      "FunctionInstanceId": "1ffac7b0-1290-4343-8ee1-2af0d39ae2c9",
      "Function": {
        "Id": "MyApp.Processors.ItemProcessor.ProcessQueueMessage",
        "FullName": "MyApp.Processors.ItemProcessor.ProcessQueueMessage",
        "ShortName": "ItemProcessor.ProcessQueueMessage",
        "Parameters": [
          {
            "Type": "QueueTrigger",
            "AccountName": "MyStorageAccount",
            "QueueName": "stuff-processor",
            "Name": "sourceFeedItemQueueItem"
          },
          {
            "Type": "BindingData",
            "Name": "dequeueCount"
          },
          {
            "Type": "ParameterDescriptor",
            "Name": "logger"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Arguments": {
        "sourceFeedItemQueueItem": "{\"SourceFeedUpdateID\":437530,\"PodcastFeedID\":\"2d48D2sf2\"}",
        "dequeueCount": "96",
        "logger": null
      },
      "Reason": "AutomaticTrigger",
      "ReasonDetails": "New queue message detected on 'stuff-processor'.",
      "StartTime": "2017-02-22T00:07:40.6017341+00:00",
      "OutputBlob": {
        "ContainerName": "azure-webjobs-hosts",
        "BlobName": "output-logs/1ffd3c7b012c043438ed12af0d39ae2c9.txt"
      },
      "ParameterLogBlob": {
        "ContainerName": "azure-webjobs-hosts",
        "BlobName": "output-logs/1cf2c1b012sa0d3438ee12daf0d39ae2c9.params.txt"
      },
      "LogLevel": "Info",
      "HostInstanceId": "d1825bdb-d92a-4657-81a4-36253e01ea5e",
      "HostDisplayName": "ItemProcessor",
      "SharedQueueName": "azure-webjobs-host-490daea03c70316f8aa2509438afe8ef",
      "InstanceQueueName": "azure-webjobs-host-d18252sdbd92a4657d1a436253e01ea5e",
      "Heartbeat": {
        "SharedContainerName": "azure-webjobs-hosts",
        "SharedDirectoryName": "heartbeats/490baea03cfdfd0416f8aa25aqr438afe8ef",
        "InstanceBlobName": "zd1825bdbdsdgga465781a436q53e01ea5e",
        "ExpirationInSeconds": 45
      },
      "WebJobRunIdentifier": {
        "WebSiteName": "myappengine",
        "JobType": "Continuous",
        "JobName": "ItemProcessor",
        "RunId": ""
      }
    }
```

What I can't find though are logs which show detail for a particular queue item where processing fails due to an exception and is placed in the poison queue.  I'm looking for these in an attempt to further troubleshoot the apparent ignoring of the MaxDequeueCount property.  Is this logged?

UPDATE: I found the post [Azure WebJobs with Storage Queue and Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mustafakasap/2015/12/26/azure-webjobs-with-storage-queue-and-exceptions) and it contained the following screenshot:

[image: Webjob console]

That screenshot shows the standard "New queue message detected..." messages (which I see both on Azure and running locally in the emulator) and it also shows "Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of X...Moving message to queue 'xyz-poison'", which I *only* see locally in the emulator.  Does the Azure-based runtime not show this info for some reason?  <s>I never see the poisoning-related messages like this when running locally in the console window or via the webjobs dashboard or when running on Azure.</s>

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Azure Storage version 8.* ? It contains a breaking change.

When a queue message object gets inserted into a message queue in Azure Storage 8, the Message Id of the original queue message object is overwritten with the unique message id of the newly inserted message.

This means that it looses its reference to the poison message and can no longer remove it.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/985

As for logging, 2 options:

1. Create your own QueueProcessorFactory and QueueProcessor - you can override the method that handles poison messages to produce more debug output. There you can also fix the issue altogether if you'd like to stay on Azure Storage 8.*.
2. Register a trace monitor. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/Error-Monitoring#tracemonitor

   ```
   var traceMonitor = new TraceMonitor()
   .Filter(p => true, "Trace Handler")
   .Subscribe(TraceHandler.Process);

   config.Tracing.Tracers.Add(traceMonitor);
   ```

Comment: Bingo!  You nailed it - this is my problem exactly.  I'm going back to 7.x in the meantime.  Not to nitpick but I don't think this is a breaking change; I think it's a bug.  A breaking change is when behavior is changed that isn't backwards compatible with previous code.  Perhaps that is true also, but this definitely seems like 'bug' category to me...?

Comment: Regarding the logging can you please clarify if I am indeed supposed to see webjob queue triggered item poison messages in "standard" webjob dashboard output when running in Azure or not?  As I was saying I see them locally only.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. The change makes sense for the storage team. It's similar to how a ORM entity would have it's Id field populated after storing it to a DB with a db generated Id field. Not quite sure what you mean with logging, but in the kudu dashboard output ( yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/jobs/continuous/YourWebJob ) I do see the entry for moving something into the poison queue: `[03/08/2017 00:39:46 > 730f59: INFO] Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 2. Moving message to queue 'queue-poison'.`

Comment: Now I know why I'm not seeing that message; it's because my poisoning is broken as I'm on 8.x...  With respect to the "breaking change" vs. "bug" question, I understand this: "When a queue message object gets inserted into a message queue in Azure Storage 8, the Message Id of the original queue message object is overwritten with the unique message id of the newly inserted message." but it appears that 8.x also somehow breaks the MaxDequeueCount behavior.

Comment: You are talking about 2 entirely different packages and teams at microsoft. One is the storage team that released the 8.x update containing the functionality change. However, they have no concept of a MaxDequeueCount, or any behavior that would trigger off of that. And then you have the azure-webjobs-sdk package & team - they handle the MaxDequeueCount behavior. Basically, azure-webjobs-sdk was simply not built with 8.x in mind. They are separate things.

Answer (score 0):

In your previous post, you have the triggered function as follows

```
public void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("azurewejobtestingqueue")] string item, TextWriter logger)
{
   if ( item == "exception" )
   {
      throw new Exception();
   }
}
```

Anything you write to the logger should appear in the logs on the WebJobs dashboard. My suggestions are:

1. Change 'if (item == "exception")' to 'if (item.ToLower().StartsWith("exception")'. Then append a number to the exception message when testing. Log the text of the queue message to the TextWriter so you can be sure that you're looking at the same message you think you are inspecting.
2. You can get the message's dequeue count as a parameter to a function. See [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/QueueOperations/Functions.cs). Check out the FailAlways method in the example. Log this to the TextWriter as well.
3. Try running this locally. All output will be written to the console window. See if you get the same behavior.

I'm really interested in finding what's causing this behavior, so make sure you let us know if you crack it!

Comment: Still trying to get it running locally - I thought your suggestion was good. I have no issues sending everything to a logger - I currently do that.  What I'm looking for is to see what the SDK is doing - to troubleshoot the behavior I want to see the SDK trying to poison (or not) the message. My `if (item=="exception")` was just pseudocode, not literal code. It was just meant to refer to an item in the queue that would cause an exception. I currently get the item's dequeueCount as a parameter (I added it) and I can see in my logs the dequeueCounts for some items going higher and higher.

Comment: Just to add a second comment - I'm having no trouble catching the exceptions - the problem is I have no visibility into why the sdk isn't poisoning the messages after MaxDequeueCount number of times.

Comment: When testing, do you have a single instance running in Azure and hitting a Storage Queue that is also in Azure?

Comment: Yes. Single instance of webjob/website and also BatchSize of 1. Using Azure storage queues. (The queues must be in Azure in order to use the sdk queue triggered function capability.)