# Azure Queue - Reappearing messages when job gets too long or exception occur in execution of Job

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I have a web-job that gets triggered by queue messages. If the job gets too long, The message reappears on the queue and a new instance of the web-job is triggered consuming the same message. That is not meant to be.

We want that message to be deleted from the message queue once the Job is triggered with that message.

We had set `MaxDequeueCount = 1`, with the thought that It will try processing the message once and then message will be moved to Poison Queue. But MaxDequeueCount is not working for us. In our Job, We are using 8.7.0.0 version of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`.

Please help!

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.NameResolver = new QueueNameResolver();
config.Queues.BatchSize = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BatchSize"]);
config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxDequeueCount"]);
var host = new JobHost(config);
host.RunAndBlock();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are hitting the message lease timeout. You should be able to extend the lease using [UpdateMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.updatemessage?view=azure-dotnet) (you should be able to extend it up to 7 days according to [this capabilities comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#foundational-capabilities)).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you mean to say we need to extend the timeout from 30 sec upto 7 days from code will solve this problem? Why MaxDequeCount set to 1 is not working ? Please Help .

Comment: Once the lease timeout is exceeded without the consumer notifying the queue that processing of the message has completed, the considers the processing a failed and then 're-queues' the message. You don't need to set it to 7, you need to fined the interval that suits the time that takes your logic to execute.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed since `2.1.0-beta1`. But there is currently no released version of 2.1.0. The latest version including the fix is `2.1.0-beta4`.

You could install the prerelease/beta version (if you want or can) to get rid of the issue. Installing the beta version is not an option for me in production, so you could install `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 2.1.0` to have a try.

For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260068/azure-webjob-not-appearing-to-respect-maxdequeuecount-property) and this [one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/985).

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs released version 2.1.0. is available.Do we need to use that version ? Is this will solved the problem of MaxDequeueCount ?

Comment: Yes, you could try to install 2.1.0 version webjob and try again.

Comment: Okay ! Thank you. I will try with this version.

Comment: With WebJobs released version 2.1.0. , It is not working. Do we have any alternate solution for this?

Comment: What the version do you use before and could you give me an example about long message.

Comment: We was using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs released version 2.0.0.                                     Example : We are saving upto 10000 records into the DB using web Job.